# Libgdx understanding screen size

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to create my own jumper type game where the player moves up through an infinite y value. The problem I am having is getting the screen size to match up with the android screen.

```
  viewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), camera);
    camera.setToOrtho(false, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

Currently I just want the sprite to be drawn in the center of the screen. I'm not worried about the game world size as it will differ from each device.

```
  camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(player.getKeyFrame(animationTime), Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2);
```

This draws the player somewhere in the upper right corner of the screen. It's my understanding that Gdx.graphics.getwhatever is used to get the dimensions of whatever your device screen is. So I'm wondering if I'm using the viewport class correctly or not?

Comment: Maybe the sprite is near as big as a quarter of the screen? For example, the  blue square in [this image](http://i.imgur.com/6nNglgH.png). I mean you did not substracted half the width and eight of the sprite size when defining the sprite origin when drawing it...

Comment: try to remove camera.settoortho

Answer (score 2):

The call to `camera.setToOrtho` sets the `camera`s position to the center. So it's P(0,0) is the middle of the `Screen`. So you are seeing everything from `P(-Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, -Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2)`, which is the lower, left corner, to `P(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2)`, which is the upper, right corner, where your player is drawn at.
There are now two posibilities:

- Draw your `player` at P(0,0)
- Set the `camera`s position to `P(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / 2, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() / 2)`

Also, don't forget to call `viewport.update(width, height)` in the `resize(width, height)` method.
And you might consider using a different `Viewport` size. It could make things easier, as you don't need to think in pixels, but in meters or another preferred unit. The `Viewport` size will then be "translated" to pixels by Libgdx, you don't need to worry about that.

**EDIT:**
As @MrPlow wrote in [this comment](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/101655/libgdx-understanding-screen-size#comment199055_101752), the `sprite`s origin by default is it's lower left corner. Also it's position is given by the lower left corner, not it's center.
While the `origin` can be changed, so that the `sprite` will be scaled and rotated arround the given `origin`, the position will always be the lower left corner.

Comment: Also, a small thing to add onto this answer, you should take into consideration that sprite origin is by default in the bottom left corner so to perfectly render the sprite it needs to be offset by half-width and half-height

Comment: @MrPlow note, that the `origin` will only affect the `rotation` and `scaling`, not the `position`. So the position will always be the lower, left corner, independent of the origin.

Comment: Yeah, I meant that the sprite position needs to be offset by half-width and half-height so that it's "properly" centered though i haven't expressed myself clearly. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: @MrPlow then, ofc, you are right. Thanks for mentioning it, it is definitly an important detail!